# Delete Method in MVC 5 using Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sorry, I'm one of those newbies to ASP.NET and I'm trying to workout why my delete method isn't working.

He's the method:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Domain domain)
{
    var rep = new Repository<Site>();
    var siteRecordFromDomainObject = _mapper.Map<Site>(domain);
    rep.Delete(siteRecordFromDomainObject);

    return View(domain);
}
```

And here is the code from repository:

```
public void Delete(TObject t)
{
    _context.Set<TObject>().Remove(t);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Would anyone be able to tell me why I am getting this error:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager.

Comment: you can check the domain variable id if that is zero or null then you will not able to fine the object in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Object needs to be already loaded or attached to the context in order to be able to remove it.

Do a Search/Find on the context for the object using an identifier. Once an object has been found then you can remove it from the context.

Given that the structure of the models involved was not know at the time of this answer here is an example of how the delete can be done.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Domain domain) {
    var rep = new Repository<Site>();
    //Assuming Repository has some means of retrieving entities,
    //get the site from repository using a common identifier
    var siteRecord = rep.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == domain.id);
    if(siteRecord !=null) {
        //if a record is found, remove it from repository
        rep.Delete(siteRecord);
    }

    return View(domain);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nkosi! This helped alot!

Comment: @GWizard, Glad to help. If this answer resolves your issue mark it as answer. When you get enough points you can up vote it as well. Thanks.